# Изолирование ServiceReference в Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, assembly

Есть Solution, в нем 3 проекта: ASP.NET WebAPI, Class Library и UnitTest

References есть с WebAPI на Class Library и с UnitTest на WebAPI и на Class Library

Class Library содержит несколько ServiceReference на WCF сервис и класс Repository, предоставляющий "наружу" досуп к методам WCF сервиса. 
Однако у меня не получается использовать экземпляр Repository ни в WebApi проекте, ни в UnitTest пректе, я получаю runtime exception с требованием добавить ServiceReference в эти проекты тоже. 
Как этого избежать и сделать так, чтобы ни WebApi проект ни UnitTest проект не знали о существовании ServiceReference и использовали только Repository?
Спасибо